# Making a PLC program for rejecting bottles using Omron PLC CP2E-N and High speed counter

Tags: plc

[image]i need to make:

1- A PLC Program on Omron PLC CP2E-N  using high speed counter E6C3-AG5B 360P/R 2M(Absolute) ,to
Reject bottles on Conveyor built.

2-The rejected bottles are  away from the point of decision (inspection Camera).

3-Take into consideration that there may be two consecutive bottles can be rejected .

4-Also I am asking if this rejection can  be done by shift register and a photocell (as a second
Methodology).

Thanks

1-actually i  took a course and see how to connect the High speed counter to the PLC but it did not cover the case where two consecutive bottles  can be rejected .

Comment: Would it be possible to be more specific on the problem or show what you've already tried ([How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar. If you need a delay between the detection and the rejection, it's almost impossible with logic block. you will have to code in structured text.
you will have to make a stack. You write the state of the bottle at the top of the stack, good or bad (0 or 1). and you read at the bottom of the stack the state to know if you need to eject the bottle or not.
if I'm not clear, I can write you an example.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).